# Angular2 - Cannot find the name - constructor, public, router

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0

I'm trying to configure auth0 API. Finally I did it and yesterday it works. Today it isn't - but I didn't change anything in code - I have files history in WebStorm.

It looks like problem is with

> constructor(public router: Router)

This is my configuration:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.7.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { myConfig }        from './auth.config';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {});

  constructor() {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  }

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }
}

import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

constructor(public router: Router) {
  this
    .router
    .events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .filter((event: NavigationStart) => (/access_token|id_token|error/).test(event.url))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.lock.resumeAuth(window.location.hash, (error, authResult) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error);
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
    });
}
```

This is what console throws:

```
ERROR in C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,20): ',' expected.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,26): ',' expected.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,36): ';' expected.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,1): Cannot find name 'constructor'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,13): Cannot find name 'public'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,20): Cannot find name 'router'.

ERROR in C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,20): ',' expected.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,26): ',' expected.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,36): ';' expected.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,1): Cannot find name 'constructor'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,13): Cannot find name 'public'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/untitled/SmartHome/src/app/auth.service.ts (40,20): Cannot find name 'router'.

ERROR in ./src/app/auth.service.ts
Module parse failed: C:\xampp\htdocs\untitled\SmartHome\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\xampp\htdocs\untitled\SmartHome\src\app\auth.service.ts The keyword 'public' is reserved (44:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
| import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
| constructor(public, router, Router);
| {
|     this
 @ ./src/app/login/login.component.ts 11:0-39
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what happens if you separate the class constructor and property to `public router: Router ; constructor(_router: Router) { this.router = _router; } ` ?

Comment: Nothing changed:
Cannot find name '_router'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this code is wrong:

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

constructor(public router: Router) {
  this
    .router
    .events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .filter((event: NavigationStart) => (/access_token|id_token|error/).test(event.url))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.lock.resumeAuth(window.location.hash, (error, authResult) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error);
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      });
    });
}
```

error message:

```
| import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
| import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
| constructor(public, router, Router);
| {
|     this
```

So constructor must belong to a class, not standalone.

for example:

```
export class YouClassService {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
}
```